# Zeppelin java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$

Tags: macos, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

When I run the code

```
val home = "/Users/adremja/Documents/Kaggle/outbrain"
val documents_categories = sc.textFile(home + "/documents_categories.csv")
documents_categories take(10) foreach println
```

in spark-shell it works perfectly

```
scala> val home = "/Users/adremja/Documents/Kaggle/outbrain"
home: String = /Users/adremja/Documents/Kaggle/outbrain

scala> val documents_categories = sc.textFile(home + "/documents_categories.csv")
documents_categories: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = /Users/adremja/Documents/Kaggle/outbrain/documents_categories.csv MapPartitionsRDD[21] at textFile at <console>:26

scala> documents_categories take(10) foreach println
document_id,category_id,confidence_level
1595802,1611,0.92
1595802,1610,0.07
1524246,1807,0.92
1524246,1608,0.07
1617787,1807,0.92
1617787,1608,0.07
1615583,1305,0.92
1615583,1806,0.07
1615460,1613,0.540646372
```

However when I try to run in the Zeppelin I get an error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.withScope(SparkContext.scala:679)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.textFile(SparkContext.scala:797)
  ... 46 elided
```

Do you have any idea where is the problem?

I have spark 2.0.1 from homebrew (I linked it in zeppelin-env.sh as SPARK_HOME) and Zeppelin 0.6.2 binary from Zeppelin's website.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK it looks like I found solution. From lib folder in zeppelin I deleted:

- jackson-annotations-2.5.0.jar
- jackson-core-2.5.3.jar
- jackson-databind-2.5.3.jar

and replaced it with version 2.6.5, which spark uses.

It works right now, but I don't know if I didn't spoil anything else.

Answer (score 1):

it seems that the spark version's problem ,the zeppelin 0.6.2 support spark 1.6 while we run spark with version 2.0. So the jars may not compatible.